# Can I run Windows app packages with batch scripts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, batch-file, windows-store-app

I've been experimenting with Microsoft's app package format, and I want to see if it is possible to run these apps *outside* of the app container with batch scripts. Some of the research I've done has pointed to some possibilities, but most of it seems unclear or uncertain if it will work. Here is an example of a batch script I would to use to run a Win32 executable:

```
"%TARGETPATH%\%TARGET%.exe"
```

How (if possible) can this be achieved for Windows apps? I would assume the parameters would be roughly the same. I know that the app package and ID would most likely be required, but I do not know what syntax to use in a batch script to achieve my goal. How can I run a Windows app through the command-line processor using batch scripts? I am also open to a PowerShell or VB script alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a command prompt (and presumably a BAT file or other script):

START ms-windows-store:

I found that here:

http://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/opening-windows-8-apps-command-prompt-or-script

It goes on about Windows 8, but I just tried in Win10, where it also works.

This lists more commandline strings:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78108-app-commands-list-windows-10-a.html