# Run Native Windows 10 Apps with Parameters

Tags: windows-10, command-line, autohotkey, windows-10-apps

Previously I installed IrfanView locally (as a normal application).
I was able to execute the following successfully in AutoHotkey to open a specific folder within the app:

```
run, "C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" N:\AutoScreenCapture\Right2Monitor
```

Now, I have uninstalled IrfanView and re-installed it as a [Windows 10 app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PJZ3BTL5PV6). When doing this, the application exe is not accessible in the same way (since it is stored now in the Windows 10 app directory).

How can I formulate a similar run command for a Windows 10 native app?
[According to a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1271572/can-i-run-windows-app-packages-with-batch-scripts) and the [forum link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78108-app-commands-list-windows-10-a.html), it should be possible to do this using a bat file pointing to a shortcut and adding the parameters at end of it? Bt I can't even get the shortcut to launch with following:

```
run, "N:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\IrfanView 64-bit App - Shortcut.lnk"
```

I prefer a run command that I can use in AHK but a PS script is fine.

Comment: There is so much information lacking here. Specifics about the script that quit working more than any other.  You don't explain installing locally but wanting store updates?  Confusing at best.  I am guessing the the votes to close this without explanation are because you have enough points here to know how to post a good question by now.  I too am going to vote to close this until you clarify things.  People were at least nice enough to not down-vote you (yet).  Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I was a lazy with the questioning. Re-wrote completely.

Comment: Are you positive the UWP version of IrfanView supports arguments?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm no familiar with UWP apps, it is [unlikely actually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/372074/how-to-run-an-exe-file-with-arguments-in-an-uwp-ap). I'll just uninstall UWP and stick to the exe.